# How to use materialize-css with React?

Tags: reactjs, npm, materialize, material-ui

I have a Meteor/React project, using ES6 modules. I've installed materialize-css using npm, but I'm not sure how to actually use the Materialize classes in my JSX code. What am I supposed to import from materialize-css? Or do I just have to include the CSS in my main index.html file?

I mostly want it for the grid system, as I'll be using material-ui for the actual UI components.

Comment: I'm starring this for later, hopefully you get a good response - I've not had luck with using ES6 imports to get `materialize-css` into my projects, I've had to resort to the old-school `<link rel="stylesheet" href="[insert CDN url]" >`, which I do not enjoy.

Comment: Are you using webpack for this? Have you come to a solution? I, too have been using the CSS for the grid only, but I get by with a link in the head tag; I'm just curious to see how others use it.

Answer (score 43):

Since I use CSS Modules, importing materialize css would scope it to that particular component. So I did the following

Step 1) install materialise

```
npm install materialize-css@next
```

Step 2) in index.html

```
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.3/css/materialize.min.css">
```

Step 3) import materialise.js in whichever component its needed

for e.g. in SomeComponent.js (for e.g. if this is about a sidenav)

```
import React from 'react';
import M from 'materialize-css';
....
// ref can only be used on class components
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  // get a reference to the element after the component has mounted
  componentDidMount(){
    M.Sidenav.init(this.sidenav);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ul className={this.props.classes}
          ref={ (sidenav) => {this.sidenav = sidenav} }
          id={this.props.id}>
        // menuItems
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

just a beginner, so I would appreciate any comments on downsides of this method

Comment: Do I also need to add JQuery and Materialize.min.js or does the npm lib takes care of it?

Comment: the npm lib takes care of it.

Comment: Nice. Also JQuery is no longer a dependency for Materialize.

Comment: I thought materialize-css and react-materialize were the same, but they are completely different. If you want to use the APIs in [React Materialize](http://react-materialize.github.io/react-materialize/?path=/story/react-materialize--welcome)

Follow the instructions there. It is better than decoding all the answers here.

Comment: I made an <h3> tag and a <select> tag nested inside a <div> tag. My select tag isn't visible. Please help.

Answer (score 23):

With NPM:

Step 1) Install materialize

```
npm install materialize-css@next
```

Check the materialize documentation for any updates. Don't miss the **@nex**t at the end. The installed version will be something like: ^1.0.0-rc.2 or ^1.0.0-alpha.4

Step 2) Import materialize JS:

```
import M from 'materialize-css'
```

Or if that doesn't work you can try  *import M from 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js'*

Step 3) Import materialize CSS:

In index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
```

OR in javascript

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
```

In order for the css import to work, you would need a *css loader*. Note that this loader is **already included** in projects built using **create-react-app** so you don't need the next steps. If instead, you are using custom webpack config, then run:

```
npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader
```

Now add css-loader and style-loader in webpack config

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "build")
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["env", "react"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now you can initialize components individually, or all at once using M.AutoInit();

Step 4) Import materialize icons:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

With CDN:

Add the following in your HTML file.

```
<!-- Materialize CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Materialize JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!-- Materialize Icons -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then, in the webpack config, add externals: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: Thanks! Using npm worked for me for initializing my Materialize'd `<select>` using React 16.6.0. Previously, using the CDN links alone didn't do it, no matter where I tried to add the code to initialize. Although I think using a separate, static JS file in the public/ dir worked, I never liked it as a long-term solution.

Answer (score 14):

You can use https://react-materialize.github.io/#/, why to reinvent the wheel.

installation `react-materialize`

> npm install react-materialize

Usage

```
import {Button, Icon} from 'react-materialize'

export default () => (
  <Button waves='light'>
    <Icon>thumb_up</Icon>
  </Button>
)
```

Sample

https://github.com/hiteshsahu/react-materializecss-template

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: React-Materialize only implements a subset of Materialize's components, so it's still desirable to find a way to use Materialize itself.

Comment: I find Material-UI as alternative to Materilize CSS. It implement most materail ui components and have plenty of examples to jump start. I even made my web page using matetial-ui see http://HiteshSahu.com

Comment: Actually React-Materialize is re-inventing the staff. If you use this library, you'll see the final classes that actually div, nav and other elements, will have the particular names, and not the same names as the materialize CSS. Which by my opinion bring a lot of confusion, and extra staff to learn. I do prefer to import CSS as @supi suggested.

Comment: @HiteshSahu sample link is 404

Answer (score 10):

There are several ways of using Materialize CSS in ReactJS. However, I always use the following easiest one.

Here you can use Materialize CSS classes just like your HTML site using only ClassName with tags.

---

1 ) Install Materialize CSS for ReactJS using NPM.

```
npm install materialize-css@next
```

2 ) Then import the minified materialize CSS file to **index.js** file.

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
```

3 ) Now if you want to use google icons add the following codes in your **public / index.html** file.

```
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

4 ) Finally to use Javascript events on input forms or other places add the following codes in your **public / index.html** file.

```
 <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

---

**N.B. =>** Since all files need to go through the index.js file, so importing your minified Materialize CSS to *index.js* once is enough. Otherwise, you need to import these CSS files to all your js files.

---

That's enough to prepare your ReactJS folder for up and running with Materialize CSS. Happy Coding.

---

Comment: Where can I see all these icons? I don't see how to use them if I don't know what they are.

Comment: For icon, you can check any of the links below: 
https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline
https://materializecss.com/icons.html

Answer (score 7):

as for the question, i think just  `npm i materialize-css` and then

```
import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";
import "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js";
```

should do the job.

---

I wanted to share a problem I faced and how i solved it.
I wanted to get [materialbox](https://materializecss.com/media.html) to work and here is how i did it

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import M from "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js";

class Image extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.imageRef = React.createRef();
  }

  onLoad = () => {
    M.Materialbox.init(this.imageRef.current);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <img
        src="..."
        alt="..."
        className="materialboxed"
        ref={this.imageRef}
        onLoad={this.onLoad}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Image;
```

an interesting thing to note - it didnt work when i was trying `M.init` inside `componentDidMount` maybe because the image doesnt load by the time the call to `componentDidMount` is made.

---

[react-materialize](http://react-materialize.github.io/react-materialize/) will surely make things easier if you want to use a lot of JS using components like modals etc.

Comment: Worked like magic! How did you figure out this import path? Where in the docs is this mentioned?

Answer (score 6):

There are possible ways that I can recommend to use:

1. One way is just include your stylesheet file in index.html and use
   className property in your React components just like this.

   > ```
   >     var myDivElement = <div className="foo" />;
   >     ReactDOM.render(myDivElement, document.getElementById('example'));
   > ```
2. Another way is to bundle all your stylesheeets in one stylesheet file and to use them as previous one.
3. One option could be to use webpack. By using webpack, it is possible to use embedded stylesheets in jsx files just by requiring stylesheet that you want to include.

   > `require("./stylesheet.css")`

   To examine in detail webpack stylesheet option: http://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html
4. Also see JedWatson's classnames repo for conditional className usage.
   https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

Comment: Unfortunately none of these help me. Materialize's CSS is conflicting with Material UI if I include the stylesheet in the HTML `<head>`. http://i.stack.imgur.com/bGzzo.png

Comment: If the customization is the main problem, this is available in Material's theme manager property. Check this part to configure theme http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes @ffxsam

Comment: but what about using method on top of jquery like `$(".modal").modal('open');` ?

Comment: @Tomasz you can write them in lifecycle methods of React.

Comment: Actually, since React uses its virtual dom infrastructure, it's not the best approach to use jquery. If you are implementing a new project, not maintaining a legacy app, try to use http://www.material-ui.com/ which provides React components that are styled with Google's material design. @Tomasz

Comment: @burakhanalkan the problem with material-ui, that it doesn't implement many components, which materialize has, e.g. collapsible, parallax, or simple grid system.

Comment: Just FYI, there seems to be a react implementation of (some) materialize components: https://github.com/react-materialize
Didn't try it yet, though

Answer (score 6):

## Solution Without index.html

1. From [react-materialize - Installation](http://react-materialize.github.io/react-materialize/?path=/story/react-materialize--welcome)

   `npm install materialize-css`

   `npm install react-materialize`

2. In your `App.js` or `App.jsx` add

```
   import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";
   import "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js";
```

---

## Usage Examples:

### Example 1

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-materialize";

export default function CustomMediaBox() {
  return <Button> Click Me </Button>;
  );
}
```

### Example 2

```
import React from "react";
import { MediaBox } from "react-materialize";

export default function CustomMediaBox() {
  return (
    <MediaBox
      options={{
        inDuration: 275,
        onCloseEnd: null,
        onCloseStart: null,
        onOpenEnd: null,
        onOpenStart: null,
        outDuration: 200
      }}
    >
      <img
        alt=""
        src="https://materializecss.com/images/sample-1.jpg"
        width="650"
      />
    </MediaBox>
  );
}
```

---

## Optionally - Adding Icons

1. Although not required, if you want to use google icons, add the following to your `App.css` or any `.css` file imported from the `App.js` or `App.jsx`

   `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');`

---

## Note

If you get an error like this:

`./node_modules/react-materialize/lib/Breadcrumb.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'classnames' in '/Users/artiomlk...`

`npm install classnames`

Answer (score 2):

Inorder to address the concern of bundle size, the easiest way to use it is as follows:

1. Include the CDN links in your index.html file
2. Initialize `M` in your React Component's constructor `this.M = window.M`
3. All the other required initializations in case of Modals and other Materialize Components can be done as mentioned in their Documentation using `this.M`
4. I like to do those initialization in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.
5. When unmounting i.e. inside `componentWillUnmount`, i use the destroy() method on the instances of initialized Materialize Components.

Answer (score 2):

- Install Materialize

```
npm i materialize-css@next
```

- Initialize

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import M from 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js';


function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    M.AutoInit();
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
         // content...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy into "imports" folder and add by

```
import '../imports/stylesheets/materialize.min.css';
```

or use this for LESS example

```
@import '{}npm-package-name/stylesheets/...';
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers didn't satisfy my biggest concern which was bundle size and importing a ton of code in order to use a few components. I've written up a solution [here](https://medium.com/@mattdlockyer/youre-using-materialize-css-wrong-470b593e78e9) that includes code splitting and an easy compilation step.

The key points are:

1. Compile base JS files (there are 4)
2. Ensure the base JS is included before your imports / bundler runs
3. Change the CSS imports to only what you need
4. Run materialize.scss through your bundler if it supports Sass or run the compilation step to get a minified css file.
5. Import individual components and activate them manually

[Read post](https://medium.com/@mattdlockyer/youre-using-materialize-css-wrong-470b593e78e9) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use CDN:

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Then `const M = window.M;` to do initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know am I too late to put this answer. 
You can use componentDidMount [like this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EboLM8OjlP4)

However, It does not use react-hooks. You'd better use react hooks (useEffects)

Answer (score 0):

How to use materialize-css with React with icons and other js features

1. yarn add materialize-css@next --save or npm install materialize-css@next --save
2. yarn add install material-icons or npm install material-icons

3.Kindly import the following like this ;
[snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAer5.png)

import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';

import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize';

import 'material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css'

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <nav className="nave-wrapper">
       <div className="container">
       <a href="#!" class="brand-logo left">Logo</a>
       <ul className="right">

         <li><a href="#!">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#!">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#!">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
        </div>
     
     </nav>
      <div className="container">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      <i class="large material-icons">insert_chart</i>
      <div class="row">
      <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6"/>
          <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
          <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate"/>
          <label for="icon_prefix">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
          <input id="icon_telephone" type="tel" class="validate"/>
          <label for="icon_telephone">Telephone</label>
        </div>
      </form>
  </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Install Materialize

```
npm i materialize-css@next
npm install react-materialize
```

- Initialize

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import M from 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js';


const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Init Materialize JS
    M.AutoInit();
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
         // content...
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install materialize css via npm through `npm install materialize-css@next`
2. Add this code `import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'` to your App.js file to add materialize globally so you don't have to call materialize in individual components.
3. Call materialize classes like so `<button className="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-4"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>`
4. For materialize fonts add `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` to your index.html in the public folder and call the icons anywhere

Side note: I am using React 18.2.0. Also, I can send you my github code for you to go through.