# Error on using Carousel in react application

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I am using MaterializeCSS in react application. On using Carousel in my render with javascript code for it. I get error at M

```
 class App extends React.Component {

   render() {
       document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
       var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
       var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, options);
  });
        return (
          <div>
     <div class="carousel">
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
      </div>
         </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Which error? Can you share the traceback? How do you import "M"?

Comment: I used this directly from materializeCSS documentation

Comment: M is undefined i got

Comment: OK, so you need to import 'M' from somewhere. I've no idea of what documentation you are talking about, can you share it also?

Comment: https://materializecss.com/carousel.html

Comment: If you npm/yarn installed it, try to `import M from 'materialize-css'`
Note: maybe you will have less issues by using a react wrapper. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499842/how-to-use-materialize-css-with-react

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize Carousel in `componentDidMount()` event of React Lifecycle to make sure if DOM has been loaded fully.

use it and let `render()` be neat and clean.

```
componentDidMount(){
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
       var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
       var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, options);
  });
}
```

Also I assume you've `options` defined in the Component.

Comment: In this case, you'll get erros, `M` is undefined and then `init` is undefined.