# 'Materialize' is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
import Materialize from 'materialize-css'
import './assets/css/main.css'

import Navbar from './components/navbar'

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const options = [
      {
        selector: '.main-text',
        offset: 0,
        callback: function(el) {
          Materialize.fadeInImage(el)
        }
      }
    ]

    Materialize.scrollFire(options)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have add package materialize css with npm in react. When I call this Materialize.scrollFire() function then it will show **Materialize is not defined**. Anyone tell me the correct way of import this Materialize. Thanks everyone...

```js
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
import Materialize from 'materialize-css'

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const options = [
      {
        selector: '.main-text',
        offset: 0,
        callback: function(el) {
          Materialize.fadeInImage(el)
        }
      }
    ]

    Materialize.scrollFire(options)
  }
 
 render() {  }
```

Comment: This question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499842/how-to-use-materialize-css-with-react

Comment: Please reproduce with codesandbox, I can see working on my machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use materialize-css with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499842/how-to-use-materialize-css-with-react)