# Characters are overlapping in React form

Tags: css, reactjs

Label and input letters are overlapping in React form.

Desired look: Top image

Current behavior: Bottom image

How can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

```
<h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Sign In</h5>
<div className="input-field">
  <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your css classes, I guess you are using materialize css for styling. For the effect you wish to see, you need to import the javascript module of it too, if not.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499842/how-to-use-materialize-css-with-react
This should help

Answer (score 0):

Better to use placeholder in the input tag instead of label tag

```
<input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="email"/>
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but with all due respect, the OP did not ask for an alternative to label. They want to know how to fix what's currently broken.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:block` in label element.

```
<label htmlFor="email" style={{display:'block'}}>Email</label>
```